# Difference between ${startDate} and #= startDate # in Kendo UI binding?

Tags: kendo-ui, template-engine

When binding to templates, many examples use the following syntax: ${startDate} and #= startDate #. There does not seem to be a difference and the use is inconsistent. The docs does not shed any light on this. Which one is recommended and is there a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between these two usage

`${startDate}` - this is jquery template style(this is also supported by kendo ) to render literal

`#= startDate #`- this is kendo template style to rendering literal values

[example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/integration/jquery-templates.html)

Comment: So no difference? Is the first one obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between ${startDate} and #= startDate # is that the first one will encode any HTML entities contained in `startDate`. The latter will embed the HTML tags in the page. It is recommended to use ${startDate}.

In short

`${startDate}` when startDate == `"<strong>foo</strong>"` will output "`&lt;strong&gt;foo&lt;/strong&gt;"`

`#= startDate #` when startDate == `"<strong>foo</strong>"` will output `"<strong>foo</strong>"`